# Multi-lingual interface in Drupal (without domain prefixes or suffixes)

Tags: drupal, localization, content-management-system

My intention was to enable multi-lingual interface only for drupal built-in interface ("my account", "administration", nodes, commenting and so on) without any additional prefixes, which relies only on user language preferences. But it just doesn't work.

Following [this tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/275705), I did this:

1. I installed 'internationalization', 'locate', 'translation' modules
2. I added the secondary language in settings
3. I have downloaded and put the translation files into drupal directory

It works when I use with prefix and does not work when with "None" setting.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what do you want to do. If you want the multilingual system work without prefixes you should go to Home › Administer › Site configuration › Languages > Configure > Language negotiation and choose 'none' - the default language is used for site presentation, though users may (optionally) select a preferred language on the My Account page.